# jqGrid how to apply custom filtering / search

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with a filterToolbar.  On one of my columns I want to do a search where for the "filter test", my custom function is called and obviously returns a true for yes it passed of false for no.

Can jqGrid do this, if so, how?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used and where is search performed - at server (server side search) or local (within local loaded array)?

Comment: Performed on a local data table (not server side) and v5.2.0

Comment: This is not supported in the current release of Guriddo. We just began to develop this feature, as we find it very interesting, and it will be available at end of this week. I will inform you

Comment: Thanks Tony.  I saw that I could use "customSortOperations" with the free fork. Maybe you could do similar as this is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Using the free fork of jqGrid you can use the following

in your colModel add the value searchoptions as so:

```
{name:'FIELD',width:120,searchoptions:{ sopt: ["cust"] },label:"Field name"}
```

then add the following property to jqGrid

```
customSortOperations: {
    // the properties of customSortOperations defines new operations 
    // used in postData.filters.rules items as op peroperty
    cust:{
           operand: "Custom",// will be displayed in searching Toolbar for example
           text: "Custom",    // will be shown in Searching Dialog or operation menu in searching toolbar

           filter: function (options) {
                        // The method will be called in case of filtering on the custom operation "cust"
                        // All parameters of the callback are properties of the only options parameter.
                        // It has the following properties:
                        //     item        - the item of data (exacly like in mydata array)
                        //     cmName      - the name of the field by which need be filtered
                        //     searchValue - the filtered value typed in the input field of the searching toolbar

                        // Get cell data as lowercase
                        var fieldData = options.item[options.cmName].toLowerCase(),
                        // Get search terms all in lowercase
                        terms = $.map(options.searchValue.split(" "), function(val){ return $.trim(val).toLocaleLowerCase(); }),
                        // A match found
                        match = false;
                        // Loop through terms and see if there is a match in the row cell data
                        $.each(terms, function(i,v)
                        {
                            if(fieldData.indexOf(v) != -1)
                            {
                                match = true;
                                // Quit the each loop
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        return match;
                    }
                }
            },
```